# Can the default view style changed?

Tags: view-styles

I am migrating a site from SP2010 to SP2013. One of the site have all the list view shown in "Shaded" style (it is a style each alternative row shows different color). When I check the View style, the style "Default" are chosen for all views on this site.

After I migrate the site from SP2010 to SP2013, all the "Shaded" style have gone. By choose the View Style, the style "Default" are chosen for all views on this site.

I suspect some client side style made the change. However I checked all those view have class like "ms-alternating". So I think the "altenating" style is setup by configure.

May I know whether SharePoint site default VIEW style can be configured? If so, how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ms-alternating is added by default to the row in a view. So you can change the CSS file, or just pick "shaded" style in the view settings.

Comment: You're right. I am just too panic for deadline. Thank you very much.